# Font ::selection height doesn't change with line-height

Tags: css, fonts

I am using the font 'Oswald' from [this URL](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap). This font has an absurd line-height by default, which I changed with `line-height`. It worked fine except for the problem that the ::selection is not decreasing accordingly and overflows.

[image]
[image]

This code replicates the problem:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap'>
        <style>
            body
            {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                font-size: 22px;
                font-family: 'Oswald';
                line-height: 1.1;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
        <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can I decrease the ::selection height so it doesn't overflow somehow?

Comment: You cannot decrease it,  the color is painted inside the area the font itself uses to be drawn.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can simply set the `height` for the lines with text and add the `overflow: hidden`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oswald&display=swap'>
  <style>
    body {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      font: 22px/1em 'Oswald';
    }
    span {
      height: 1.2em;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    ::selection {
      background-color: #fa08;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
  <span>Lorem Ipsum</span>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well yes but I need the solution to work with paragraphs too